# MATLAB error: "Matrix dimensions must agree" when not dealing with matrices

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I am having the following difficulty: I would like to have a graph of a function plotted but I keep getting the error that "Matrix dimensions must agree."

The code I am using is as follows:

```
x = -1.5:0.1:1.5;
y = 1/sqrt(9 - x.^2) + 1/sqrt(4 - x.^2) - 1;
plot(x, y);
```

The error as it appears in the command window is:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Possibly the problem lies where I define `x = -1.5:0.1:1.5;` which makes MATLAB thinks this is a matrix, but all I want to do is have function values plotted at intervals of `0.1` between `-1.5` and `1.5`.

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operations like multiplication or division can have special meaning for matrices. If you're interested in "normal", element-wise operations, you need to use the dot before the operator, i.e.

```
 y = 1./sqrt(9 - x.^2) + 1./sqrt(4 - x.^2) - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! You're an absolute star! It's small things like that that can have me start smashing things after being stuck for a few hours on it...